# Cambiar valor de un atributo en método de una clase

Tags: python, api, pandas

realizo conexión a una API privada a la cual tengo que indicar la fecha que quiero los datos, estos lo realizo mediante self.__today = datetime.today()+timedelta(days= - 0) indicando la fecha del día. El problema surge que hay veces que no hay datos del día y arroja response.status_code = 404, por lo cual hay que cambiar la fecha probando días anteriores ejemplo 1 día hacia atrás self.__today = datetime.today()+timedelta(days= - 1), voy probando días hacia atrás hasta obtener datos.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import base64


class Net:

def __init__(self):
    self.__today = datetime.today()+timedelta(days= - 0) ## inicializo el atributo con fecha del día
    self.__URL_LOGIN = 'http://100.0.0.11:52/account/login'
    self.__URL_BASE = 'http://100.0.0.11:52'
    self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G = f"{self.__URL_BASE}/api/tables/Cm/g/data/a_ws?date_from={self.__today}&date_to={self.__today}"

def __login(self):
    pwd = base64.b64decode("aX853fhfh89543589345834hfklsdfdsjhkh").decode("utf-8")
    usr = base64.b64decode("d8454385nkdgdfgsddnfsdfdsdsNTUzNw=").decode("utf-8")
    payload = json.dumps({"username": usr , "password" : pwd})
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.request("POST", self.__URL_LOGIN, headers=headers, data=payload)
    tok = json.loads(response.text)
    token = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+ v for k,v in tok.items() if k == 'access_token'}
    return token

def get_datos_g(self):
        token = self.__login()
        response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        if response.status_code == 404: ## si NO hay datos del día
           self.__today = datetime.today()+timedelta(days= - 1) ## intento cambiar el valor 
                                                                atributo con una fecha 1 día 
                                                                hacia atrás (la idea sería que 
                                                                pruebe y si no hay datos ir -2 
                                                                días atrás y así hasta 
                                                                encontrar datos.)
                                                                                                            
           response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
           data = json.loads(response.text) ## me sigue dando error, creo no esta cambiando el 
                                               valor del atributo self.__today , lo estoy 
                                               haciendo bien? cambiar el valor del atributo
                                               solo para este método?
                                               
                                               
           df_g = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(str)
            return df_g
                 
        else: ## SI hay datos del día
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            df_g = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(str)
            return df_g


gestor = Net()
df_3 = gestor.get_datos_3().filter(['mo_class','name','mo_distName'])
```

Como podría hacer para que cada vez que arroje error 404 el método intente hacer la consulta días hacia atrás hasta que se encuentren datos , desde ya gracias por su tiempo... saludos

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: @CandidMoe  esta en las líneas,  como cambio el valor del atributo para ese método?  esta bien hecho la forma en que quiero cambiar el valor del atributo?  como hago para que cada vez que me da el error 404, hago lo que necesito, gracias

Comment: lo que pudieras hacer es utilizar recursividad

Comment: @ChristianGtz me podrías guiar como hacerlo? gracias

Comment: @ChristianGtz. No uses recursividad cuando basta con iterar.

Comment: @CandidMoe si pense en utilizar una iteracion, pero al estar manejando self, estos valores no se modifican en la variable print(self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G), ya que no se ha cambiado la variable __URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, si no la __today

Comment: Aunque otra es utilizar las variables de clase

Comment: el problema creo es la definición del atributo self.__today, debo sacarlo como atributo de clase __init__ porque  si bien puedo cambiar su valor desde el método, al llamar a la función self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G vuelve a utilizar el atributo inicializado con la fecha que da error  y no la modificada en el método! ahora como hago para que este tiempo  sea variable de clase  y poder utilizarlo en el método e ir cambiando la fecha? desde ya gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: @isvo podemos utilizar los metodos de clase y variables de clase, para que puedas modificar los datos, dame 5 min te muestro como quedaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pudieramos utilizar variables de clases.

```
class Net:    

__today = datetime.today()+timedelta(days= - 0) ## inicializo el atributo con fecha del día
__URL_LOGIN = 'http://100.0.0.11:52/account/login'
__URL_BASE = 'http://100.0.0.11:52'
__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G = f"{__URL_BASE}/api/tables/Cm/g/data/a_ws?date_from={__today}&date_to={__today}"

def __login(cls):
    pwd = base64.b64decode("aX853fhfh89543589345834hfklsdfdsjhkh").decode("utf8")
    usr = base64.b64decode("d8454385nkdgdfgsddnfsdfdsdsNTUzNw=").decode("utf8")
    payload = json.dumps({"username": usr , "password" : pwd})
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.request("POST", self.__URL_LOGIN, headers=headers, data=payload)
    tok = json.loads(response.text)
    token = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+ v for k,v in tok.items() if k == 'access_token'}
    return {'Authorization':'Bearer test'}

def get_datos_g(cls, _days):
        token = cls.__login()
        cls.__today = datetime.today()+timedelta(days=_days)
        print(cls.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G)
        # response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        response = requests.request("GET", cls.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        while response.status_code == 404:
            cls.__today = cls.__today + timedelta(days=-1)
            response = requests.request("GET", cls.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        
        data = response.json()
        df_g = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(str)
        return df_g


gestor = Net()
df_3 = gestor.get_datos_g(0).filter(['mo_class','name','mo_distName'])
```

y asi quedaria con recursibidad, tal vez no sea la mejor opcion pero te agrego ambas para que puedas testear lo mas optimo para ti, estuve tratando con el API de MetaWeather y me funcionaron ambos ahora solo seria adaptarlo a tu problema

```
 def get_datos_g(self, _days):
        token = self.__login()
        self.__today = datetime.today()+timedelta(days=_days)
        params = f"date_from={self.__today}&date_to={self.__today}"
        self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G = self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G + params
        # response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        if response == 404: ## si NO hay datos del día
            self.get_datos_g(_days =- 1)
        
        data = response.json()
        df_g = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(str)
        return df_g
```

De este ultimo, lo que hice fue separar la url_query y poner una variable de llamada params asi cuando cambies los valores de tu variable de instancia se asignaran a los parametros, ahora pensandolo bien podrias utilizar lo mismo sin utilizar variables de clase y solo reasignar los valores de params xD

ya te agrego el codigo y con una iteracion quedaria.

```
    def get_datos_g(self):
        token = self.__login()
        params = f"date_from={self.__today}&date_to={self.__today}"
        self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G = self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G + params
        # response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        while response.status_code == 404:
            self.__today = self.__today + timedelta(days=-1)
            params = f"date_from={self.__today}&date_to={self.__today}"
            self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G = self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G + params
            response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        
        data = response.json()
        df_g = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(str)
        return df_g
```

disculpa por muchas vueltas, estube viendo la manera de no utilizar tanto codigo.

Comment: Gracias @Christian Gtz quedo resuelto!  lo que me genero dudas ahora es como manejar estos caso, o sea, atributos de clases una vez inicializados con x valor puedo? y/o como ?  modifico su valor en un método de la clase? es posible? me surgieron muchas dudas al respecto como así también el manejo de variables de clases .. gracias por todo...

Comment: si puedes modificar los valores, la diferencia es que si estos valores cambian en cada instancia que tengas de tu clase estos van a cambiar, tener cuidado con esto.

https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-de-clase-y-de-instancia-en-python/

te dejo un link donde lo explican.

variables de clase y de instancia no son iguales, y metodos de clase como de instancia no son iguales, (cls, self)

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el `if` por un `while`:

```
def get_datos_g(self):
    token = self.__login()
    response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
    while response.status_code == 404:  
        self.__today = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=- 1)
        response = requests.request("GET", self.__URL_QUERY_TABLE_G, headers=token)
        
    data = json.loads(response.text)  
    df_g = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(str)
    return df_g
```